# Django Rest Framework global pagination and pagination_class are not working

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-pagination

My settings:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS': 'rest_framework.pagination.PageNumberPagination',
    'PAGE_SIZE': 2
}
```

My pagination Class:

```python
from rest_framework.pagination import PageNumberPagination


class CustomNumberPagination(PageNumberPagination):
    page_size = 5
```

My Testing View Class:

```python
from rest_framework.pagination import PageNumberPagination
from .pagination import CustomNumberPagination


class Testing(generics.GenericAPIView):

    queryset = Testing.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TestingSerializer
    pagination_class = CustomNumberPagination

    def get(self, request):
        print PageNumberPagination.page_size  # 2
        print self.pagination_class.page_size  # 5
        queryset = self.get_queryset()
        serializer = self.serializer_class(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

I can print out the page_size of PageNumberPagination and CustomNumberPagination in my console correctly.

However, passing `page` as a parameter doesn't have any effect. I couldn't get either global paginations or pagination_class in each view to work. I am not sure what went wrong, but it seems that most people did the same thing and just worked for them. I'd appreciate any suggestions for me.

### Updates

Just got some inspirations from my selected answer below.

Since I will have to write a lot of customizations in my overwritten `get()`, I just updated my `get()`:

```
from rest_framework.pagination import PageNumberPagination
from .pagination import CustomNumberPagination


class Testing(generics.GenericAPIView):

    queryset = Testing.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TestingSerializer
    pagination_class = CustomNumberPagination

    def get(self, request):
        queryset = self.get_queryset()
        page = self.request.query_params.get('page')
        if page is not None:
            paginate_queryset = self.paginate_queryset(queryset)
            serializer = self.serializer_class(paginate_queryset, many=True)
            return self.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)

        serializer = self.serializer_class(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Comment: Watch out with self.request.query_params.get('page') - if no page is specified your endpoint will return all objects in queryset :) Usually in such case it is nice to return just first page. so ...get('page', 1)

Comment: Thank you for your friendly reminder :D I will have to make `page` optional because our FE doesn't support pagination now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a look how it is done in drf itself:

```
class ListModelMixin(object):
    """
    List a queryset.
    """
    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())

        page = self.paginate_queryset(queryset)
        if page is not None:
            serializer = self.get_serializer(page, many=True)
            return self.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)

        serializer = self.get_serializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Hope that this will help you - as is self-explanatory;

You used `GenericAPIView` - and overwrite the get - you should use the `get_paginated_response` method to achieve pagination.

Happy coding.

Comment: This is inspiring and I just solved my problem! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was passing wrong argument in query param for page no.
It was `page` but I was passing `page_no`